# How should I populate my new program to Debian repository?

Tags: debian, repository

I want some of my programs to be in standard Debian repository to be available for users of Debian/Ubuntu, first in Sid, then, if eveything will be OK, eventually available for just `apt-get install`.

I included `debian/*` files for `debuild`, created custom repostiory with this package, tested on some archs and filed an ITP request to debian issue tracker.

No non-automatic replies was given for the ITP hovewer...

What am I doing wrong? How should I make my program available for installation from central repository? Or I shouldn't try getting there unless there are many users or my program?

Comment: Maybe a look [here](http://www.debian.org/devel/join/)?

Comment: This page more suggests about keeping old packages up rather than adding new.

Comment: Yes but there is the discussion about the "sponsors" and the idea that only a debian maintainer(DM) can upload packages to the archive...

Comment: Shall I try contacting some existing maintainer (for example, by filing a RTP) about my package or try becoming a single-package (initially) maintainer?

Comment: No, there is proper channels to do what you want. Check the [New maintainer guide](http://www.debian.org/devel/join/newmaint)

Answer (score 2):

With a "ITP" (intent-to-package) you announce that you want to prepare a package for Debian and care that it goes into the repository. It is not a request to help you with this. Its main purpose is to avoid duplication of work.

If you want that someone else does the packaging, you can fill a "RFP" report (ready-for-packaging). But depending on the package you suppose, is not very probable that someone have time for this.

You have already created a `debian/` subdirectory, so most of the work is probably already done. I suggest you to become maintainer of your package. Upload your package to http://mentors.debian.net/ and find a sponsor by filling a **RFS** (request-for-sponsorship).
See e.g. http://mentors.debian.net/intro-maintainers for more information.